# Show that any path $Y, \tau'$ in a $T_2$ space is second countable.

Tags: general-topology

We may use the fact that any continuous function from a compact $T_2$ space onto a $T_2$ space  is closed.

A hint I received is let $\{U_n\}, n \in \mathbb{N}$, be a countable basis for the usual metric topology on $[0,1]$, which is known to be second countable. Then $[0,1] - U_n$ is closed for each $n$. Prove that $\{Y-f([0,1]-U_n)\}, n \in N$, is a basis for $\tau'$.

Answer (score 1):

Take a point $y$ in the path and an open neighborhood $W$ of $y$. Then the fiber $F=f^{-1}(y)$ is a subset of the open set $V=f^{-1}(W)$. We can cover each point $x\in F$ by a base element $U_{n_x}⊆V$. Since $F$ is compact, there are finitely many such
$U_{n_1},...,U_{n_l}$ which suffice to cover $F$. But then 
$$y\in Y-f\left(I-\bigcup_i U_{n_i}\right)⊆W$$
That means the set
$$\left\{Y-f\left(I-\bigcup_{i=1}^l U_{n_i}\right)
\middle| l\in\Bbb N, U_{n_i}\in\mathcal B\right\}$$
forms a (countable) base for your path.
I don't know how to do it without taking finite unions of the base elements, though. This proof, however, works for any [perfect map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_map)

Comment: 'Then the fiber $F$...' what exactly do you mean by fiber here?

Comment: The preimage of a point is often called a *fiber*.

Comment: How would you say this uses the fact that any continuous function from a compact $T_2$ space onto a $T_2$ space is closed?

Comment: @David: $f(I-\bigcup U_n)$ is closed, so its complement is open.